# Dont understan what exactly I can do with cloud computing such as AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, bluehost

I have read a couple articles and I know the basic concept of cloud computing..But I still don't know what exactly I can do with this service.

As a mobile application developer, I have developed a couple of iPhone applications. I have a Bluehost account and I have MySQL database in there. I have a couple PHP scripts on my server and on device side, it sends http request to the server to get the data from database in XML format. That is basically how I designed and implemented my applications..

Now what can I do with a cloud computing? If I use a cloud computing service such as AWS then how it is going to change the structure of my application?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud computing doesn't necessarily have to change the structure of your app. The main benefit of cloud computing in a lot of cases is scaling.

Right now if your iPhone apps become really popular and overload your current host, what do you do?

Using the cloud, you could spin up new instances (servers) on demand almost instantly. Another benefit is you only pay for what you need. Of course, depending on the situation, it might require changes to your structure to take advantage of scaling features.

edit: Specific to AWS, they have a service called Elastic Load Balancing. Take a look: http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/